# Updating DB from onLoadFinished calls onLoadFinished again and again

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider, loader, android-cursorloader

I have a situation in which I need to insert a row at a date and update all the entries after a particular date in an activity.

For this, I thought I'll load the entries after the date with a `LoaderManager` Callback and use a `ContentProviderOperation` array to update all of it in batch from the `onLoadFinished()` method.

The problem I am facing is that I have `setNotificationUri` to the cursor and because of that the `onLoadfinished` is called again, which inserts the row again and the cycle continues (not setting the notification `Uri` is not an option for me).

Is there any elegant solution to stop the recursive call?

Below is the simplified code of my `onCreateLoader` and `onLoadFinished`:

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        //retrieve data before the start date
        mStartDate = ProjectContract.getDateFromDb(mUserProjectEntryData.getAsString(ProjectContract.ProjectEntryTable.COLUMN_DATETEXT));
        Date nextDate = Utilities.addDays(mStartDate,1);
        String sortOrder = ProjectContract.ProjectEntryTable.COLUMN_DATETEXT + " ASC";
        Uri projectEntryUri = ProjectContract.ProjectEntryTable.buildProjectEntryWithStartDateUri(mProjectId,
                ProjectContract.getDbDateString(nextDate));
        return new CursorLoader(
                this,
                projectEntryUri,
                PROJECT_ENTRY_COLUMNS,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder
        );

    }

@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mDbOperations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        long newTotalCount;
        String selection = ProjectContract.ProjectEntryTable.COLUMN_PROJECT_ID + " = ? AND "
                + ProjectContract.ProjectEntryTable.COLUMN_DATETEXT + " = ? ";
//Some code to calculate the entry needed
        mDbOperations.add(
                ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ProjectContract.ProjectEntryTable.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValues(mUserProjectEntryData)
                        .withYieldAllowed(true)
                        .build()
        );

        while (data.moveToNext()) {
data.getString(COL_DATETEXT));
            newTotalCount = mCurrentWordCount + data.getLong(COL_WORD_COUNT);
            mDbOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ProjectContract.ProjectEntryTable.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ProjectContract.ProjectEntryTable.COLUMN_TOTAL_WORD_COUNT, newTotalCount)
                    .withSelection(selection, new String[]{
                            Long.toString(data.getLong(COL_PROJECT_ID)),
                            data.getString(COL_DATETEXT)
                    })
                    .build());

        }
//Hacky solution I put in just to make the code working.
//        data.close();
        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ProjectContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, mDbOperations);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `cursor = contentresolver.query(); iterate cursor; cursor.close();` inside some other thread ... without loaders at all ...

Comment: I'll try using an AsyncTask.. that would work right? Call the Content provider in doInBackground and iterate through the cursor in the onPostExecute ... 
Since my query is pretty small it should work fine. But what if it was large and the screen rotation would mess up the AsyncTask implementation right?

Comment: no... do all stuff in doInBackground  ... there is no UI involved(or if you need to inform UI do it in  onPostExecute - do not iterate there)... or simply `new Thread { public void run() { /* do all stuff here, remeber to close the cursor */ } }.start();` ...oh i see your edit ... AsyncTask should be retained http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/10/asynctask-screen-rotation.html

Comment: Hmmm.. let me try to implement that... thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the db operations to a separate thread without using the loader callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Decided to write an answer for people who struggled with this problem a bit like me.

I had 2 tables with a foreign key and I needed _ID from 1 table to make a foreing key in the second, that's why I had to insert each row separately (not as a bulkInsert). It caused my Loader to update after each insertion. I've solved this problem by preventing insert method in ContentProvider to call notifyChange and notifying ContentProvider manually after each bulk operation.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any elegant solution to stop the recursive call?

The solution is simple, close your cursor to stop recursive call. Just add this -

```
data.close();
```

after applyBatch of oparation.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try like below:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Inside onLoadFinished");
    // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
    // old cursor once we return.)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    // The list should now be shown.
    if (isResumed()) {
        setListShown(true);
    } else {
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: lol, Did you read the question? OP is using the Loader API to get cursor **but not to use with UI(no ListView involded)** ... Your code is irrevelant - look like random copy&copy paste from some guide/tutorial

Comment: I'm really not using a list, nor an adapter. I don't need to display the results, but process them and update some values in them..